Scraping text in whitebox
I am trying to collect some Dutch historical election data. Below you see the code I have been using. I still need to figure out how to iterate the process for every 'Gemeente', but my main problem now is that I am not able to scrape the election results, which are contained in a box (i.e., the results object does not capture that information). Do you have any suggestions on how to proceed? Thank you.
rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4545L, verbose=F)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

# Navigate to the URL
url <- 'https://www.verkiezingsuitslagen.nl/verkiezingen/detail/TK19250701/663214'
remDr$navigate(url)

dropdown1 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'id', value = "2")
dropdown1$clickElement()

dropdown2 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'id', value = "3")
dropdown2$clickElement()

option <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "/html/body/main/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/select/option[2]")
option$clickElement()

results <- remDr$findElement(using = 'class name', value = "whitebox")


All the data is stored in a series of JSON files, it is a matter of searching the network tab of your browser's developer's tools.
The below code will pull a list of regional codes and retrieve a file of results.
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)

#the regional codes are stored here;
codes <- jsonlite::fromJSON("https://www.verkiezingsuitslagen.nl/verkiezingen/StemmingChartUitslagDataJson?stemmingId=10778")
codes <- codes$UitslagPerRegio

#election results are store in JSON format that this base URL
baseURL <- "https://www.verkiezingsuitslagen.nl/verkiezingen/detailJson/TK19250701/"

#for the town of Goor
regionCode <- codes[codes$RegioNaam=="Goor", ]$StemregioId

#results are store in a complex list here:
jsonlite::fromJSON(paste0(baseURL, regionCode))

